# How to get dictionary in a list of dicts based on key value?

Tags: python

A function receives a list of emails and calls other methods which can return a payload with status `success` or `error`. If a method returns `error` it doesn't stop the flow, the function continue to the following method.

For each email, I want to get the first payload with `error` or the last payload with `success`, that way, if the first method returns `error` and the last `success` I can see where and if it failed in some step before.

Note:
If the first step returns `error`, the second `error` and the last `success`, I want to see only the payload of the first step.
If the first step returns `success`, the second `error` and the last `success`, I want to see only the payload of the second step and so on.

Current code:

```
def main(emails):

    result_from_step_1 = [
        {"email": "test1@gmail.com", "status": "success", "step": 1},
        {"email": "test2@gmail.com", "status": "error", "step": 1},
    ]

    result_from_step_2 = [
        {"email": "test1@gmail.com", "status": "error", "step": 2},
        {"email": "test2@gmail.com", "status": "success", "step": 2},
    ]

    result_from_step_3 = [
        {"email": "test1@gmail.com", "status": "error", "step": 3},
        {"email": "test2@gmail.com", "status": "success", "step": 3},
    ]

    payloads = result_from_step_1 + result_from_step_2 + result_from_step_3

    response = [get_status(payloads, email) for email in emails]
    return response

def get_status(payloads, user_email):
    for payload in payloads:
        if payload["email"] != user_email:
            continue
        response = payload
        if payload["status"] == "success":
            continue
        break
    return response

emails = ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"]
response = main(emails)
print(response)
```

Any other ideas?

The nested loop feels a little complex for future maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a list of dictionaries, create a dictionary whose keys are the emails. Then you can implement your logic when building the dictionary.

```
result = {}
for payload in result_from_step_1 + result_from_step_2 + result_from_step_3:
    if payload['email'] in user_emails:
        if payload['email'] not in result:
            result[payload['email']] = payload
        elif result[payload['email']]['status'] == 'success':
            result[payload['email']] = payload
```

The logic here is that it will replace any `success` with the next payload for that email; if they're all success, it keeps replacing them until the last one. If there are any `error` results, the first one will replace the previous `success`, but it won't be replaced any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
successes = [x for x in your_list if x["status"] == "success"]
if successes:
    return successes[-1]
return your_list[0]
```

For each email you want either the last payload with status=success, or first error payload. Phrased that way it means that, either there are any successes (in which case we return last one), or there aren't (in which case we return first error, but since there are only non-successes=errors, the first error is also the first payload).

Now map this over list of your emails, filter out payloads unrelated to them, apply the above and collect to dict. You're clearly python-savvy, you can do it on your own ;)

Comment: Hey Filip, the list can have payloads for different emails, also I want to check if there is an error, not a success, if there is only success I just need to return the response from the last step.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_status(payloads, user_email):
    return [payload  for payload in payloads if not (payload["email"] != user_email or payload["status"] == "success")]
```